# Is my JSF PrimeFaces application HTML5?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, mojarra

This seems like a very elementary question, but I would like to go with it anyway.

My web app uses Mojarra + Primefaces, and it uses the **p:chart** element which renders as a **canvas** element, which I thought was an HTML5 feature.  Yet when I view the source of my pages in the browser I get:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

instead of

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Firebug shows my charts are indeed rendered as **canvas** tags, so am I getting HTML5 or not?

If I am not, is there some setup parameter that I need to make it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document is being served as XHTML 1.0 Transitional (because that's what your doctype says) but that doesn't mean that you cannot use canvas element.

Browsers try to render whatever you give them. If you give them XHTML 1.0 but you use canvas elements, it will try to render it. And most of the times it will do it well.

Although probably your document is not valid according to W3C.

Comment: I sure would like to make my output standards compliant if possible.  Any idea why Mojarra would be outputting this kind of tag salad?

Comment: Don't you have a template for your app? There you can specify which **doctype** you need, HTML5, XHTML 1.0…. If you don't have a template, do it on your own file (the one with the p:chart).

Comment: Well dang.  If stackoverflow gave out badges for you-shoulda-known I guess I just earned on.  I was somehow assuming that the Faces Servlet formed its own document from scratch but now it is blindly obvious that it doesn't.  Thanks from the clueless.